# asp.net , setting submenu to not visible from load function in .cs file

Tags: asp.net, submenu, visible

This is the menu control I want to modify from the aspx.cs file .

I am trying to use something like

```
cool.Items[0].ChildItems[5]. _________
```

There is no visibility option here though. How can I touch the visibility of a submenu from the .cs file?

Comment: What are the types of these items in this random variable name?

Comment: <asp:MenuItem Text="Routing" NavigateUrl="Page1.aspx">
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Attachments" NavigateUrl="Page1-1.aspx"       ImageUrl="~/images/attach.png" />